# What feeds should we have in The Pod Bay?

Tags: discussion, chat

We were recently having a conversation in [The Pod Bay](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay), our chatroom (get involved!), about what feeds we should have.

These can be RSS feeds, and can contain anything you can fit in an RSS block.

Also, one feed per post, the accepted answer should be community wiki and should include all feeds currently aggregated.

#### Format:

> ### Feed Name:
>
> http://a-link.to-the.feed
>
> An optional push for the feed.

Note that we already have a feed for questions posted in both our [meta](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com) and the [main site](http://space.stackexchange.com). I hold the keys to the room, they won't be changing.

**Suggestions posted below that reach an equal or greater than [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) number of upvotes will be included in our chatrooms's list of feeds.**

Comment: A reminder: one feed per post, current feeds are here: RSS feeds in place:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9682/the-pod-bay?tab=feeds.

Answer (score 5):

### NASA Image of the Day- A̶d̶d̶e̶d̶  Removed

http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss

**Example feed** (click on the image to display latest results):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### XKCD - Added

http://xkcd.com/rss.xml

**Example feed** (click on the image to display latest results):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## NASA Space Flight - Added

http://www.nasaspaceflight.com/feed/?cat=-6,-378

**Example feed** (click on the image to display latest results):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Mars Daily

http://marsdaily.com/marsdaily.xml

Answer (score 2):

### StackExchange Blog - Added

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/

**Example feed** (click on the image to display latest results):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Astrobites - Added (... aaaaand removed) *

http://astrobites.org/feed

**Example feed** (click on the image to display latest results):

[image]

* This feed has been acting up since long, dumping 10 items at the same time while not updating in between. Removed to preserve the chat flow without distractions by pages long list of old items.

Answer (score 1):

### Space News

http://www.spacenews.com/articles.xml

Answer (score 1):

### Planetary Society's blog

http://www.planetary.org/system/rss/channel.jsp?feedID=328434498

Answer (score 1):

### Spaceflight101 - Space Flight News and Updates

http://feeds.rapidfeeds.com/55870/

**Example feed**:

> **[China ready to Launch its first Lunar Lander & Rover on Sunday](http://www.spaceflight101.com/change-3-mission-updates.html)**
>
> China is ready to launch its first Lunar Lander & Rover, one of the
> most ambitious space missions conducted by China. After successfully
> putting the Chang'e 1 and Chang'e 2 spacecraft into orbit around the
> Moon, China is heading into the second phase of its Lunar Exploration
> Program that has the ultimate goal of manned flights to the Moon.
> Chang'e 3 is set for launch from the Xichang Satellite Launch Center
> atop a Long March 3B rocket on Sunday at 17:30 UTC. The vehicle is
> planned to insert itself into lunar orbit on December 6 before making
> its adventurous descent and landing on the 14th.

Answer (score 0):

### SpaceflightNow Upcoming Launches - Added * (... aaaaand removed) **

http://www.feed43.com/space-launch-schedule.xml

* Due to RSS displaying updates to the launch schedule alone, and frequent updates making previous state stale, the feed is set to display as a *ticker feed* via a slide-down ticker overlay that periodically appears at the top of the room, and is not persistent.

** SpaceflightNow changed their [launch tracker page](http://spaceflightnow.com/launch-schedule/) and sadly doesn't support RSS anymore.

Answer (score 0):

### Astronomy Picture of the Day Archive

http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/archivepix.html

Answer (score 0):

### NASA JPL News and feature stories

http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/multimedia/rss/news.xml